# Installing software in unix where is the best place?

Tags: linux, unix, local, bin

Hi i am trying to answer this question however im not sure that if /usr/local/bin is the best place or /opt could i get any help on this please

You installed the software initially in /usr/local/bin. Given what the program does say where you think the best place to put it might be and why. This might actually be /usr/local/bin so do not assume it has to be a different location.

Comment: When you install on your linux box, it doesn't matter where. There is only FHS guidance where to install. See [**File Hierarchical System**](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html) for the complete story.

Answer (score 1):

For software which has only a single/couple of binaries, I use /usr/local/bin .. but as soon as it becomes a large bundle (such as Oracle Database), I place it in /opt/company/product such as /opt/Oracle/12c/